# Byte combination generator and sequencer

Tags: java, regex, recursion, binary, byte

First things first, this question is going to be 2 questions about the same code packed into one. Also, please excuse my ignorance to the language, I only just learned Java in the past two weeks and this is part of my first major project.

Consider the following code:

```
public class TESTCODE {
```

`public static ArrayList<String> bytePossibalitiyGenerator(int bits, String current) throws Exception {
    ArrayList<String> binaries = new ArrayList<>();
    if (bits%8 != 0) {
        int crash = bits%8;
        throw new Exception("The bit count that you have entered is not divisable by 8:" + "\n" + "There is a remainder of: " + Integer.toString(crash));
    } else {
        if (current.length() == bits) {
            binaries.add(current);
            return binaries;
        }
        // pad a 0 and 1 in front of current;
        binaries.addAll(bytePossibalitiyGenerator(bits, "0" + current));
        binaries.addAll(bytePossibalitiyGenerator(bits, "1" + current));
        System.out.println(binaries.toString());
    }
    return binaries;
}

//The method below is supposed to format out the whitespace between binary strings and arrange the 
//data in such a way that each possible outcome is on a new line.
    //TODO  Add a parser for the size of the byte ex. if the binary string is comprised of all of the possible
    //TODO  outcomes for 1 byte than every 8 instead of appending a space, append a new line.

public static String binarySequencer(String input) {
    StringBuffer toReturn = new StringBuffer();
    //This StringBuilder is a safety precaution to ensure that if the algorithm is to be 
    //run again, the value of each previously read and appended string position is nullified
    //so that it is not re-appended to the StringBuffer
    StringBuilder inputSB = new StringBuilder(input);

    //Setting the booleans for which type of string the input was (The raw binary array itself, or the array converted into a string)
    boolean rawBinaryArrayOutput = Pattern.compile("^[0-1,\\s]+$").matcher(input).find();
    boolean stringBinary = Pattern.compile("^[0-1\\t]+$").matcher(input).find();

    //This boolean is to check whether the loop has previously passed over 1 byte for sequencing
    boolean hasPassedAByte = false;

    //Safety if statements, because who doesn't love Java Exceptions and stack traces...
    if (rawBinaryArrayOutput == false && stringBinary == false || rawBinaryArrayOutput == true && stringBinary == true) {
        System.out.println(rawBinaryArrayOutput);
        System.out.println(stringBinary);
        //TODO Find a way to print the stack trace...
        throw new InputMismatchException();
    } else {
        int runLength = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < inputSB.length(); i++) {
            int j = 0;
            if (stringBinary == true && rawBinaryArrayOutput == false) {
                if (runLength == 8 && (inputSB.charAt(j += i) == 0 || inputSB.charAt(j += 1) == 1)) {
                    toReturn.append(Character.toString(' '));
                    runLength = 0;
                    hasPassedAByte = true;
                } else {
                    if (hasPassedAByte = true && runLength == 8 && (inputSB.charAt(j) != 0 || inputSB.charAt(j) != 1)) {
                        toReturn.append("\n");
                        runLength = 0;
                        hasPassedAByte = false;
                    }
                    while (i + 1 < inputSB.length() && (inputSB.charAt(i) == 0 || inputSB.charAt(i) == 1) && runLength != 8) {
                        runLength++;
                        toReturn.append(inputSB.charAt(i));
                        inputSB.insert(i, null);
                        i++;
                    }

                }
            } else {
                if (rawBinaryArrayOutput == true && stringBinary == false) {
                    //Insert code for formatting the raw binary array output
                    System.out.println("You haven't added this code yet :p");

                }
            }
        }
    }
    return toReturn.toString();
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
String toBeSequenced = "";
for (String s : bytePossibalitiyGenerator(16, "")) {
    toBeSequenced += s + "\t";
}
System.out.println(binarySequencer(toBeSequenced));}}`

Now for the questions:

1: For the `boolean rawBinaryArrayOutput` I am using the       `java.util.regex.Pattern` class' `compile` method to search for `{0-1 , \\s}` characters in the string being input and if it finds any of those, it sets the `rawBinaryArrayOutput` to true. Is there a way to make it only set `rawBinaryArrayOutput` to true if at least 1 of all of those values are found?

2: In the `binarySequencer` method I have a `StringBuilder inputSB` automatically take the value of `String input` so that I can modify the values in the `StringBuilder`. On line 75 I am trying to set the value at position `i` to `null` so that if the while somehow loop runs over the same position twice, it won't append anything to the `StringBuilder toReturn`, but Eclipse gives me a compile error on that line `The method (int, Object) is ambiguous for type StringBuilder`. What does that mean, and how can I fix it?

3: I have an if statement at the begining of the `binarySequencer` method that checks to see if `rawBinaryArrayOutput == false && stringBinary == false || rawBinaryArrayOutput == true && stringBinary == true` and if they are then it will `throw new InputMismatchException();`. How would I get this to also print out the stack trace, if that is even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. For `rawBinaryArrayOutput` you can try with regex:

   ```
   ^([01](,\s)?)+$
   ```

   which will accept string with `0` or `1` sequence (one or more char)
   separated by optional `,\s` part. However for bits input, maybe
   better would be:

   ```
   ^(?:(?:[01]{8})+(?:,\s)?)+$
   ```

   which will accept only one or more of 8 character sequence of `0` or
   `1`. The `?:` part are for non grouping by regex.
2. The `The method (int, Object) is ambiguous for type StringBuilder`
   as far I as know means that StringBuilder class has two similar methods, in this case it is:
   `insert(int, String)` and `insert(int, char[])`, and compiler don't
   know which one you want to call, bacause as a second variable you
   used `null`, and null reference can be converted to an expression of any class type. Try with:

   ```
   inputSB.insert(i, (char[]) null);
   ```

   for example. Then it is obvius which method you call, even if it is
   not relevant for a case.
3. I would not use [InputMismatchException()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/InputMismatchException.html), it would be better to throw another custom exception. With proper regex there will be no option for double true match, and with double false you can just print useful info.

Comment: I ended up changing the `binaryPossibalityGenerator` so that the only way it can be called is through another method that automatically changes its return value to a string and returns that, so there is no need for the `binarySequencer` to detect if the string that was input was straight from the array, or converted into a string.